# Automate the boring stuff with python - google search via beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Has anyone had trouble calling browser after executing the code mentioned below?

I have executed code from Pycharm version 2019.1 and I have done it from CMD but no results.

My Code:

```
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser as wb
import bs4

print ('Googling...')
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
linkElements = soup.select('.r a')
linkToOpen = min(5, len(linkElements))
for i in range(linkToOpen):
   wb.open('http://google.com'+linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

No error messages, unable to call the browser.

Comment: windows or unix?

Comment: Chris, operating system is windows. I can confirm selenium module opens up the browser ok.

Comment: if you print out `linkToOpen` its actually 0, so your bs4 call is wrong

Comment: do you have a recommendation of how to fix it? Any documentation I shall go through in order to make it work?

Comment: only advice is to try get better at googling stuff, there are plenty of answers for your question with a simple search e.g "python get google search"

Comment: Python as a 'print' function, an interactive shell and a step debugger. You may want to learn to use them so you can debug this kind of trivial issues by yourself...